# ListView and IGrouping

Tags: xaml, listview, igrouping

I have a linq2sql query that results in an `IGrouping<Users, string`>, that I want to bind to a ListView:

```
<ListView Name="UsersListView">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</Listview>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -2):

You should make `CollectionViewSource` in `Page.REsources` like below. And bind your `CollectionViewSource`
The important thing is that `IsSourceGrouped = true`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedData" IsSourceGrouped="true" Source="{Binding GroupedData}" />
</Page.Resources>
```